# How to collect user defined functions in a liberary in nodjs?

Tags: node.js

I have several `functions` but I dont know how collect user defined functions in liberary to reuse them in all around the nodeJs projec?

Comment: Read some of the source code to see how "require(x)" works - I think you're wanting to do something similar.

Comment: Hi @thegleep I'm newbie to programing. Thanks I will do it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something like this:
In your preferred folder, create a file like user.js
Then, define a class, E6 way :

```
class Users {
//if you need a constructor, but it's not mandatory
constructor(username,email,otherParamYouNeed){
this.username = username;
this.email = email;
this.otherParamYouNeed = otherYouNeed
}

//then organize your user functions there

userFunctionThatDoesSomething(){
//do what you need
}
userFunctionThatDoesAnotherThing(){
 // do what you need
}
}

//then export the class
module.exports = {Users}
```

After, in the file in which you need to call those functions :

```
var {Users} = require ('/path/to/user.js');
//if you have constructor in your class
var user = new Users(username,email,otherParamYouNeed);
//if not
var user = new Users;
```

After that, you will be able to use the functions you declared in the class in the file you have required the class in, like :

```
user.userFunctionThatDoesSomething(etc..);
```

Have a look at https://www.sitepoint.com/object-oriented-javascript-deep-dive-es6-classes/